# Is there any way to use Pa11y Actions to call a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, accessibility, pa11y

I am running into an issue with Pa11y Actions where the "Click element..." action doesn't trigger the JavaScript "onclick" function to run. Is there any way to use Pa11y's Actions feature to call a JavaScript function on a page?